# After page refresh js file change path Angular

Tags: angular, .htaccess, nginx

I have an angular app, all it's fine until i want to reload the page.
If i reload that page the path for the js file it's changed. All my js file are into root folder and for example if my page it's /contact/ after refresh path for js file become /contact/name.js.

My question is how i can write some htaccess content or what nginx settings need to be done for solving this type of issue.
I try a lot related to htacces but without succes

Thanks,
Alin.

Comment: Can you take a look at https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: hi, i use that htacces rule allready and no succes

Comment: more e3xactly i'm able to see this error  "responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."

Comment: hope you can find some solution from this https://stackoverflow.com/q/58596709/3090685

Comment: And here is the configuration of nginx: 
```server {
 listen 8080 default_server;
 listen [::]:8080 default_server;
 root /var/www/html;
  index index.html;
     
       location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      }
}```

Answer (score 0):

The problem when you reload an Angular app is that the current URL does not really exist on the server. Hence you need a way to prevent the URL to be sent to the server but still be handle by Angular. In your app.module.ts where the Router Module is imported add the following parameter:

```
useHash:true
```

it should looks like the: `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash:true })`

If this does not work, look for HashLocationStrategy in angular, it shall be the solution.
[documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy)

Answer (score 0):

In this example is there a way to only add hash to js and css files?

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: 'base', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: BasePageComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: DashboardComponent },   
      ]
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```